# True superscripts and subscripts in math mode

Tags: fonts, fontspec

The `realscripts` package enables one to use true superscripts and subscripts provided by some fonts like `Linux Libertine` in regular text. This particularly improves the typesetting of `footnotemarks`. Is there a way to use these in math mode for squares, cubes etc.? Is it advisable?

Edit: I am using `XeLateX'.

Comment: I think you'd rather want to find a font family that provides an open type math font. For Linux Libertine there's `Libertinus`, just to give an example.

Comment: Please tell us which LaTeX format you employ: pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, or something else? The fact that you set the 'fontspec' tag suggests that you might be using  either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX -- please confirm.

Comment: Don't forget there are several smaller sizes used for sub- and superscripts, not sure if would look good to have one of them in a different glyph. And wouldn't you run into spacing problems when you get e.g. `x^{2e}?

Comment: it's fine to use these "true superscripts" for what they're designed for -- footnote markers.  but in math, as soon as you get a superscript such as `^{2x}` there's likely to be a mismatch, and a full set of letters and symbols will never be implemented as unicode superscripts, since the set is open-ended.

Comment: @Christoph90 Thanks. I am indeed using `Libertinus Math` for math mode. However, it does not use true superscripts and subscripts.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for pointing out the potential mismatches when using true superscripts in math mode. I guess it does not make sense.

Comment: @remco Good point. I guess it does not make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's fine to use these "true superscripts" for what they're designed for --
footnote markers. but in math,  as soon as you get a superscript such as `^{2x}`
there's likely to be a mismatch, and a full set of letters and symbols will
never be implemented as unicode superscripts, since the set is open-ended.

also, as pointed out by remco in a comment, different sizes are used for
sub- and superscripts when they are multi-level, whereas the "true superscripts"
typically come in only one size.